# Raw query on repository class using Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I need to create  a raw query in  the repository class, but i'm geting and error

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
   public function usertoExpirate(){

     $query = 'SELECT email 
     FROM user 
     WHERE type NOT IN("deleted", "admin") 
     AND  expiration_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -3 MONTH)';
    
     $statement = $this->getConnection()->prepare($query);
     $statement->execute();
     $user_to_expirate_password = $statement->fetchAll();

     return $user_to_expirate_password;
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
Undefined method 'getConnection'. The method name must start with either findBy, findOneBy or countBy!
```

Comment: Well let's see.  The undefined method error message strongly implies the class does not have a method with that particular name.  You might be a bit confused with the find stuff but that is because the repository class actually lets you do stuff like findByType without adding the actual method.  It's just a distraction really.  So how can you get a connection?  Turns out EntityManager::getConnection exists.  I'll leave it as an exercise in reading code for you to determine how to get the entity manager from a repository.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of Symfony 3.4](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/repository.html) you need to get the entity manager, not the connection. Try it like this:

```php
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function usertoExpirate() {

        $query = 'SELECT email 
        FROM user 
        WHERE type NOT IN("deleted", "admin") 
        AND expiration_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -3 MONTH)';
   
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($query)
            ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Right idea as far as getting the entity manager but your code is mixing up SQL and DQL.